# "Посмотреть небольшой экскурс", да?

Tags: выбор-слов

> Правда, чтобы внимательно рассмотреть подробности, вам понадобится как
>   минимум театральный бинокль. А можно заплатить евро и **посмотреть
>   небольшой экскурс**, там даются хорошие крупные планы мелких деталей
>   мозаики.

Comment: Экскурс можно совершить или сделать - обычно в своих _рассуждениях_ на какую-то тему. Буквально, это "отклонение от курса", его нельзя "посмотреть" и пр. - это не разновидность  "экскурсии".

Comment: Спасибо. Автор непременно прочтёт. Саш, а ***поучаствовать в небольшом экскурсе*** неверно?

Comment: Я отталкивалась в своем ответе вот от этой статьи: В День России более 2000 человек приняли участие в культурно-историческом экскурсе «История есть священная книга народов… Н.М. Карамзин» https://ulkul.ru/news/organizations/_2000_.html  Принять участие - участвовать - поучаствовать

Comment: Трактовка _исторического экскурса_ как коллективного мероприятия (с соотв. возможностью участия в нём) мне кажется некорректной, она противоречит словарным толкованиям _экскурса_ как такового. Историческим экскурсом может быть названа глава монографии по истории основного её предмета или отдельная лекция (или часть лекции) по историческому аспекту какого-л. предмета или вопроса (экскурс совершает автор или лектор).

Comment: Саша, земной поклон. А разве на экскурсии экскурсовод не может пригласить своих жертв совершить некий экскурс? Мы убиваем автора. Ещё и Апокалипсис им своевольно прочитан...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы "передвинула" акценты: в бинокль можно только разглядеть, а для того, чтобы внимательно всё рассмотреть, и нужен платный экскурс.

*Правда, чтобы **разглядеть подробности**, вам понадобится как минимум театральный бинокль. А можно всего за евро поучаствовать в небольшом экскурсе и на хороших крупных планах **внимательно рассмотреть** детали мозаики.*

Comment: Я полагаю, что речь о *живьём*! Это путеводитель по римским храмам с использованием искусствоведческих находок автора. Быть или не быть книге, решится на днях, но очень уж в сыром виде она представлена издателю...

Comment: Ну, тогда "видео" можно безболезненно убрать. Одну секунду.

Answer (score 1):

А можно заплатить 1€ и стать участником экскурса, где укрупнёно демонстрируются фрагменты мозаичных панно.

Comment: Может, нищасный глагол *посмотреть* заменить? Напр., "*включиться* в небольшой экскурс"... Плохо?

Comment: ... и отправится в экскурс.

Answer (score 1):

Плохо: посмотреть экскурс, **крупные** планы **мелких** деталей, *мелкие детали* — плеоназм (в данном контексте)

**А можно заплатить евро за небольшой экскурс, в котором детали мозаики показаны крупным планом.**